# Building a prefixer type using typescripts Template literal type feature

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I would like to prefix all keys in an interface using the literal type feature, but my understanding of types is too limited.

What I got so far is the following:

```
export type Prefix<K extends string, T extends string> = `${K}${T}`;

export type Prefixer<K, T extends string> = {
    [Prefix<P in keyof K>]: K[P];
};
```

Usage would be:

```
interface Animals {
   fish: any;
}

type SuperAnimals = Prefixer<Animals, 'super'>;
```

Can someone help?

Comment: To my mind, it should work like this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKVgDMCWIA8A0nKDMAHYAmAznNTFDuQOYA0cAKiSGVbfYxYA+OAF44AAwAkAb0IBfWR3kSA3ACh1oSLATJUGbHmBQi3XjTgAlYAGNolfAKZs4AQ3KIh7LqQqXnYTE4GXU4cLgAbTQ4JjgAa2BECCw4YjdaQ1wCDnY0IQBdAC406IKNeQ1NJjIoLDdbVABBchwAWzcAG1pQiLhcagALEo9ECs0kFDgAZQBXFCgW9q7acSzjUyWO7vYAcmp5k12hVSA but seems to cause error. Even the example of key remapping in the 4.1 announcement seems to result in the same issue. Hmmm. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#key-remapping-mapped-types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for this appears to have changed since the [TS4.1 announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#key-remapping-mapped-types)/ TS4.1 beta.

Working from

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types

it seems we can:

```
export type Prefix<K extends string, T extends string> = `${K}${T}`;

export type Prefixer<K, T extends string> = {
    [P in keyof K as Prefix<T, string & P>]: K[P];
};


interface Animals {
    fish: any;
}

type SuperAnimals = Prefixer<Animals, 'super'>;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKVgDMCWIA8A0nKDMAHYAmAznNTFDuQOYA0cAKiSGVbfYxYA%20OAF44AAwAkAb0IBfWR3kSA3ACh1oSLATJUGbHmBQi7LqQo06DJsxHiZ6uC7gBtNHCZwA1sEQQWHDEAIa0hrgEHOwCdnAAZOhCALoAXMEeyRryGppMZFBYIQDGqACC5DgAtiEANrROrnC41AAW6SHkiNmaSChwAMoArihQFdV1tOIRxqbjNfXsAOTUIyZLQqpAA)

For extra fun you can define `Prefix` as

```
export type Prefix<K extends string, T extends string> = `${K}${Capitalize<T>}`;
```

resulting in props like `superFish` instead of `superfish`.